# nav buttons not displaying inline

Tags: html, css, inline, nav

Ok so my navigation is set to inline-block, but for some reason, in safari, it shows up like this. It works fine in chrome but I cannot figure out what I need to change. It fixes itself when I change the size of my web browser window. Any help would be appreciated.

*Note I'm using Susy with this which is why there is `@include span(12)`

[image]

*Desired output*
[image]
CSS:

```
nav{
     @include span(12);
nav ul{ 
     @include span(12);
     list-style: none;
     display: inline;
     float: right;

}

li{ 
   display: inline;
   float: right;
   padding: 2%;
}
}


nav ul li a {
     display: inline-block;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: white;
     background-color: #FF4343;
     border-radius: 49px; 
     -moz-border-radius: 49px; 
     -webkit-border-radius: 49px; 
     border: 0px solid #EB0000;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 10%;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: small;
     text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="desktop-nav">
 <ul id="desktop-nav">
 <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
 <li><a class="scroll" id="green" href="#form-header">Contact Us</a>    </li>
 <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Our History</a></li>
 <li><a href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: did @stephenpassero's idea work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing `width:100%;`. That should make it go all the way across.